# Using an HTML ID with a dot / period in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input form e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a.b">
```

I want to print its value whenever I click on it using the `console.log()` javascript function.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a.b" onclick="console.log(a.b.value)">
```

Obviously, Javascript complains that a is undefined and that the property b of value does not exist. The only way I found of doing this was to rename my field using _ instead of a . (period). I end up with

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a_b" onclick="console.log(a_b.value)">
```

Is there a better way? Can I escape dots in identifiers? I am aware that . is an invalid character in Javascript identifiers but it is not in HTML. Can I get around this issue using jquery?

Comment: A *better* way is to use external event handlers

Comment: @SterlingArcher interesting. Do you have any good pointers?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener here's the MDN on addEventListener, use that combined with `this.value`. Inline events like `onclick="derp()"` are considered bad practice.

Comment: It is bad practice to reference elements by just its id.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript uses `.` notation to use object. And you can only escape when using as String. So the answer is No.

Why not just using `this`

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="a.b" onclick="console.log(this.value)">
```

If you are playing with it, that is fine but as someone already pointed in comments, do not use inline events. Instead add events on elements

```js
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("a.b");
    checkbox.onchange = function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        console.log("checked");
      } else {
        console.log("un checked");
      }
    }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="a.b">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by doing `console.log(window["a.b"].value)`. I wouldn't suggest this as accessing elements directly like that is not a best practice, but it will do what you are asking.